# Github - merging fork into master (locally)

Tags: github

So i have the following problem:
Back when i started programming, i FORKED a repository (using github for windows)  for a browser-game. For some time now, i made stuff, did git commit and issued a pull request using the webpage.
The original author did authorize my pull request and my changes went live.
Recently, i have become an "official" author on the original repository.

So i dont want to work on my "fork" any longer but instead dev on the original.
Using github for windows, i decided to "clone" the original repo.
My github now shows my forked (AncientSion/FieryVoid) repository and the original (Aatu/FieryVoid).

Now what i would like to do is somehow "merge" my forked repo into my local clone of the original repo and from there commit to the master repo directly, that way deploying my local, not yet commited changes from my fork to the live version while at the same time getting rid of fork repository.

However, i have no idea if that works and if it does, how.
Can someone please advise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the Github for Windows interface supports this, but this can definitely be done via the git bash console. This is untested, but the steps ought to be correct, since I've done something similar (identical, in fact) before. This assumes that your clone, `AncientSion/FieryVoid`, is up-to-date with `Aatu/FieryVoid`, which can be done with a pull followed by a merge, or, to avoid merge commits, with a `git pull --rebase`. So now you have `AncientSion/FieryVoid` and `Aatu/FieryVoid`, both present locally, with `AncientSion/FieryVoid` ahead of `Aatu/FieryVoid` by a few commits. What you need to do is pull in those commits into `Aatu/FieryVoid` by running the following:

```
cd  path/to/local/clone/of/Aatu/FieryVoid
git remote add local_pull path/to/local/clone/of/AncientSion/FieryVoid
git pull local_pull master
git push origin master
```

Couple of assumptions:

1. You were working on the `master` branch of `AncientSion/FieryVoid`. If not, replace `master` in line 3 with your branch name.
2. `origin` is a remote that tracks the online repo `Aatu/FieryVoid`